# What is the future of the Sys.require, ASP.NET AJAX loader script?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, loader

Does anyone know if this script will continue to have a future or is it DOA and being replaced by another component? I use its functionality a lot and would like to know if there is a better alternative or what the future holds for it...

To clarify, I'm talking about the async loader features in start.js.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of the ASP.NET Ajax Library (not to be confused with ASP.NET AJAX) was officially released and development on it ceased before it was complete.  You shouldn't use it. I've wrote an article on the subject.

The same team at Microsoft has produced a new script loader, DeferJS, which is the next logical evolution of Sys.require.  You can find the latest version of it here: https://github.com/BorisMoore/JsDefer

Comment: Cool, I'll go check it out. I had been using the loader a lot and was hoping it wouldn't just disappear.

Comment: I hadn't seen that yet, thanks for the FYI.  Updating my answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

There's not going to be any further development on sys.require, but the existing scripts and services will not disappear.  Microsoft has taken considerable measures to maintain backwards compatibility with its older technologies, so there's no reason to think that what you have working now will suddenly stop working at some point in the near future.

Microsoft seems to be going in the direction of integrating with the open source jQuery library.  Here's a blog post about it: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/28/jquery-and-microsoft.aspx.  jQuery is very powerful and flexible, and has both **[built in support](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)** as well as **[a plethora of plugins for AJAX](http://plugins.jquery.com/projects/plugins?type=47)**.

Answer (score 0):

There's also RequireJS (http://requirejs.org/), which is quite mature, and somewhat easier to use. It's not from Mircosoft, but it may be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can [try this](https://github.com/fredyang/matrix.js,)

it is an extensible resource loader, and it does dependencies tracking.